# About Server and website

Tags: web-applications

I'm planning to make a site that can store a lot of photos and share like in photobucket or flickr, 
and i don't know what's the right server for me. 
 to be honest i don't know much about servers. i was planning to get a server named bluehost  but my friend said that's not the right server for me, he said i can't store more than 20 thousand files in bluehost server.

will you please help me about what's the right server for me and please tell me more about server to help me about my problem and tell me about what do i really need to know about my problem or situation.

thanks in advance.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/133242)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the terms **server** and **http daemon**. The *server* is the piece of hardware, "the computer" staying 24/7 online. On the server, the physical machine, are running programs called **daemons**.

For each **internet service** there are some number of daemons implementing the required **protocol(s)**. The protocol of the Internet service called **word wide web** is called **hyper text transfer protocol**.

So you want a http daemon that can deliver static files like photos quickly.

I think the best option is **nginx**, although there are others as well.

Either way, apache is not one of the lightest http daemons, it's a beast meant to be robust and feature-rich, not fast. (which does not mean that the light ones are not robust)

Comment: why is apache not light? because of memory consumption? what would be a lighter deamon?

Comment: Yes, and it's slower. Lighter: nginx. Read my answer.